# How to implement a DateField into a custom user model's registration form using UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users, django-crispy-forms

I have a registration form set up which worked, then I tried adding a date of birth field to the user model and add that to the registration form. The DateField appears on the registration form however whenever I submit the data to register a new user, I get the error message "Enter a valid date" ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb6EB.png)). Here is what I have in my forms.py:

```
BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = (2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991,
                      1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981,
                      1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971,
                      1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962, 1961,
                      1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951,
                      1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945, 1944, 1943, 1942, 1941,
                      1940, 1939, 1938, 1937, 1936, 1935, 1934, 1933, 1932, 1931,
                      1930, 1929, 1928, 1927, 1926, 1925, 1924, 1923, 1922, 1921,
                      1920, 1919, 1918, 1917, 1916, 1915, 1914, 1913, 1912, 1911,
                      1910, 1909, 1908, 1907, 1906, 1905, 1904, 1903, 1902, 1901, 1900)


class DateInput(forms.DateField):
    input_type = settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS   #This is ['%d %B %Y']


#Create a class which inherits from Django's UserCreationForm class and add fields necessary for my users
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(required=True, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': DateInput()
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        date_of_birth = self.pop('date_of_birth', None)

        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit)
        Profile.objects.create(date_of_birth)
        return user
```

Note: I am trying to test the save method but cannot since I can't submit yet, therefore if that looks wrong then I haven't been able to see why yet.

This is my views.py method:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'games/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You seem to have 2 conflicting widgets for the date field the `DateInput()` given in the `class Meta`, and the `SelectDateWidget` given in the `widget` kwarg. I don't know how Django addresses this conflict, but perhaps this is causing the issue. (Clearly the SelectDateWidget is the one actually rendered on the page, but it's possible the validation might be being done against the other one?)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I removed the DateInput class and widget declaration inside Meta, and replaced the date_of_birth to: `date_of_birth = forms.DateField(required=True, input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))` but I still get the same issue.